# Plotting multiple densities in ggplot2: How to add an extra variable with a different scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scaling

I will try to describe my problem using a simplified example. I am trying to plot several densities with ggplot2, something like:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
x <- replicate(5, rnorm(100)) 
colnames(x) <- paste0("x", 1:5)

ggplot(melt(x), aes(value, color = Var2)) + geom_density()
```

[image: density plot]

This works as expected. Now, I would like to add a new variable with a very different scale:

```
z <- cbind(x, y = rnorm(100) * 50)
ggplot(melt(z), aes(value, color = Var2)) + geom_density()
```

[image: density plot with exrta variable]

This produces the expected graph, but not the one I would like to make unfortunately. I would like to keep the original scales of both axes, so that the differences between the first five densities would still be visible, and the density of the new variable would appear as flat.

Is it possible to do this in a simple way? Like telling ggplot to overlay the new density without changing the scaling? Or telling ggplot to ignore a variable when computing the limits of the axes?

I could consider a manual solution that would save the limits of the axes in a first step, and then specify them when the graph is made with the new variable. But that might not be the most elegant solution and might require a lot of extra code. I would prefer avoiding this kind of solution if possible (especially because my case is actually much more complex and implies multiple graphs with `facet_wrap()`)

Any suggestions or hints would be most welcome. Many thanks in advance!

PS: To give you more background information, I am trying to plot several posterior distributions against their prior distribution (the flat one). I only have draws from the prior, not its exact density function - otherwise I would just have overlaid this prior with `stat_function()`.

Comment: Could it be as simple as specifying a baseline x range that would work for most cases, by adding something like `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-4,4))`?

Comment: That would definitely work if the range defined in xlim was always the same, or almost the same. The problem is that I am generating a huge number of such figures, all with (very) different ranges. That's why I was hoping there would be a simple workaround to make these graphs automatically, without having to specify manually the range of the x-axis. But maybe that's just not feasible... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a cool way to change get a second Y axis:

First let's recreate your chart in a more generalized format. I'm going to create a data frame X (Note: it's Capitalized)

```
X <- data.frame(x)

g <- ggplot()
g <- g + geom_density(data = X, aes(x1, colour= "X1"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = X, aes(x2, colour= "x2"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = X, aes(x3, colour= "x3"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = X, aes(x3, colour= "x4"))

g
```

Which produces a the density chart

[image]

OK, cool now let's recreate the issue in z you mentioned

```
Z <- data.frame(z)

g <- ggplot()
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x1, colour= "X1"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x2, colour= "x2"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x3, colour= "x3"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x3, colour= "x4"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x3, colour= "x4"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(y, colour= "y"))
g
```

Which gives

[image]

OK, now here's we can subset a second axis by the difference given in

```
z <- cbind(x, y = rnorm(100) * 50)
```

Namely, 50. but you can really make it whatever proportion you would like.

```
Z <- data.frame(z)

g <- ggplot()
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x1, colour= "x1"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x2, colour= "x2"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x3, colour= "x3"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x3, colour= "x4"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(y/50, colour= "y"))
g <- g + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*50, name= "Y Second Axis"))
g
```

Which gives us the desired double y axis!

[image]

You can also do a double x axis as well.

```
g <- ggplot()
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x1, colour= "x1"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x2, colour= "x2"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x3, colour= "x3"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x3, colour= "x4"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(y/50, colour= "y"))
g <- g + scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*50, name= "x Second Axis"))
g
```

[image]

Hope that helps!

Edit:

After clarification it looks like the desired result would simply to keep the original x-axis limits but to add the new larger density. We can do that both in my style and with the melt format you were using.

```
g <- ggplot()
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x1, colour= "x1"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x2, colour= "x2"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x3, colour= "x3"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x3, colour= "x4"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(y, colour= "y"))
g <- g + xlim(range(-4:4))
g
```

OR

```
ggplot(melt(z), aes(value, color = Var2)) + geom_density() + xlim(range(-4, 4)
```

[image]

Edit 2: This gives us a plot with the right axis but it removes values from the density plot (as pointed out by Remek, and a solution in the comments which was correct from Jon Spring). Can we get a plot that leaves the density values unchanged? Yes! we need coord_cartesian() this will also us to preform a 'zoom in' rather than exude values outside of our limits.

Here's the solution in both styles:

```
g <- ggplot()
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x1, colour= "X1"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x2, colour= "x2"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x3, colour= "x3"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x3, colour= "x4"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(x3, colour= "x4"))
g <- g + geom_density(data = Z, aes(y, colour= "y"))
g <- g + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-4, 4))
g

ggplot(melt(z), aes(value, color = Var2)) + geom_density() + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-4, 4))
```

both of which will produce the desired results!
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @CrayCrayTown! I was probably not clear enough in my original post: What I would like to do is to keep the scale of all variables, but not use the scale computed by ggplot for the axes, which is too large because of the last variable. Instead, I would like to scale the graph as if the last variable was omitted - the density of this latter variable would then appear very flat, but this is what I am looking for. Is it possible to do this without using the manual solution?

Comment: Oh sure, I see what you mean.  I will edit an addition to do that.

Comment: Thanks (and sorry for the late reply). That looks good, but it also looks like the density is now truncated to the interval range(-4:4): If you look at the second graph I posted, the density does not go above 0.01, whereas on your last graph it goes over 0.1! So that's clearly something different that is being plotted here. If this is what's going on here, do you know how to use all the data points when computing the density, even if the graph is restricted to a small interval like the one you used? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that as well. It's possible that the densities require that the function be 'closed' over the interval. I wonder we could try something different and get a better representation of y. I'll give it another run.

Comment: Alright, I think we officially have fully explored this concept, I think essentially that John Spring had it right from the start. We needed to use coord_cartesian() as it will zoom over the plot rather than changing the plot itself. I think this ended up being good general information for how you can handle axis issues in lots of different ways!

Comment: We have explored a lot, thanks! But we are also a bit back to square one: The limits of the x-axis now have to be specified manually, which I initially wanted to avoid. I am generating many figures, without knowing in advance what the scales should be, and would therefore like to let ggplot decide based on the first five ones (ignoring the last one). I'll try to figure something out and post it if I find a nice solution.

Comment: I am sure we can parameterize the input we are feeding coord_cartesian(xlim()) command. I think that's all that's left right? Maybe we can just use like the median value over a mean to specify more precisely zoom in over the values we've looked over? We could also use like values 2 and 4 from a five number summary of the values, something like that.

Comment: Thanks. As I wrote to Jon Spring above, this works for the simple example I provided, but I could not extend it to the more complicated example with facet_wrap() unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the pre-combined data to specify range?

```
ggplot(melt(z), aes(value, color = Var2)) + 
  geom_density() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(melt(x)$value),
                           max(melt(x)$value)))
```

or, we could use the same `melt(z)` but back out the data with the new variable:

```
ggplot(melt(z), aes(value, color = Var2)) + 
  geom_density() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(subset(melt(z), Var2 != "y")$value),
                           max(subset(melt(z), Var2 != "y")$value)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works for the simple example I provided above, but I could not extend it to my more complicated case with facet_wrap() unfortunately. I have been trying for some time now, looking for a solution that would allow me to do this in compact form with facet_wrap(), without having to generate all these graphs separately and then combining them. But this may just not be possible.